# Change timer setting on a bathroom fan (sharing a switch with the light)

Tags: lighting, fans

In our new house, the bathroom fan goes on about 3 minutes after the light has been switched on (single switch for both), and goes off about 10 minutes after the light has been switched off. I would like to decrease the latter duration to something 3 minutes, or even remove the timer function so that the fan is only on while the light is on.

However, the fan is behind a casing that has no screws or other bits that can be removed. I tried pulling it lightly, but it wouldn't come out and I don't know if popping the lid out from the edges with a screwdriver won't break the lid or damage the fan behind.

Is it likely that any adjustable timer setting *would be* behind the case, or is that just a 'constant' built into the fan circuit? Ultimately, I would prefer to deactivate the fan altogether than to have it run for so long, but I'm not sure how the lid (pictured below) is meant to be removed.
[image]

Comment: Do you own this house or are you renting it?

Comment: Make and model would be very helpful. Have you looked online?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica: renting, but happy to do some minimal interventions as long as commensurate with my DIY skills (low)

Comment: @HoneyDo you're completely right, unfortunately I've no other info (e.g. from the house plan), and the Wernig make printed on the casing is all I know. Before posting I checked other questions on this site, and a few YT videos, but none were helpful for my question

Comment: It appears your fan is a Wernig Silent ECO series fan. Here is a link to the manual. https://www.wernig.at/fileadmin/Daten/Pdfs/Register_3EN.pdf The lag time on the fan is adjustable 1 to 7 minutes. Although it doesn't precisely explain how to remove the front panel to access the electronics it appears that the plastic front panel can be compressed slightly from the sides to remove. Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice find, thank you!! I don't really understand from the manual what user switch there is on the electronic board that the user can work in order to steplessly adjust the lag time within the 1-7min range...